# cannot verify xyz’s certificate, certificate has expired (CentoS 6)

Tags: certificate, wget, centos6, rhel6

Getting this message using wget to retrieve data from urls.

I've successfully patched multiple RHEL7 machines using the method on [RHEL bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1842174), however I'm unable to successfully update a couple of older CentOS 6 machines.

On the CentOS 6 machine, per this tweet, I've copied the blacklist file and then ran `update-ca-trust extract`, but continue getting "certificate has expired"

The temp workaround is adding `--no-check-certificate` to the wget calls, since these are local trusted URLs.

Is there a better solution in place for EL6 systems short of rebuilding servers with a newer OS?